# Query to count length of consecutive time for each item

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this query below that is supposed to count how many consecutive minutes System_Idle_Process is 10 or below but this logic does not seem to reset time back to 0 when the System_Idle_Process goes above the 10 percent threshold.

```
    if object_id('tempdb..#tp') is NOt NULL Drop Table #tp
;WITH
  -- This table contains all the distinct date 
  -- instances in the data set
  dates(ServerName,Event_Time) AS (
    SELECT ServerName, Event_Time
    FROM [MetricData].dbo.[ServerCpuUtilization] --#ServerCpuUtilization  --
    Where [Event_Time] between  dateadd(hour, datediff(hour,'20110101',dateadd(Hour, -(800*24),getdate() ) ),'20110101') and 
                          dateadd(hour, datediff(hour,'20110101',dateadd(Hour, 0,getdate() ) ),'20110101') --> dateadd(day,0, datediff(day,0,getdate()-1))
    and System_Idle_Process <=10 
  ),
  -- Generate "groups" of dates by subtracting the
  -- date's row number (no gaps) from the date itself
  -- (with potential gaps). Whenever there is a gap,
  -- there will be a new group
  groups AS (
    SELECT ServerName,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition by ServerName ORDER BY FORMAT([Event_Time] , 'yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:00')) AS rn,
      dateadd(mi, -ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition by ServerName ORDER BY FORMAT([Event_Time] , 'yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:00')),
      FORMAT([Event_Time], 'yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:00')) AS grp,
      Event_Time
    FROM dates
  )
SELECT * into #tp
FROM groups
ORDER BY ServerName,Event_Time, rn

Select * from #tp
SELECT
  COUNT(*) AS consecutiveDates,
  MIN(grp) AS minDate,
  MAX(Event_Time) AS maxDate
FROM #tp
GROUP BY grp
ORDER BY 1 DESC, 2 DESC
```

Here is a sample data file on the intial_data tab.

Sample data

```
ServerName  Event_time
SomeServer1 4/22/2022 16:16:20:1620
SomeServer1 6/23/2022 21:47:02:472
SomeServer1 6/23/2022 21:48:02:482
SomeServer1 6/23/2022 21:49:03:493
SomeServer1 6/23/2022 21:51:03:513
SomeServer1 6/23/2022 21:52:03:523
SomeServer2 6/23/2022 22:03:05:35
SomeServer2 6/23/2022 22:04:05:45
SomeServer2 6/23/2022 22:05:05:55
SomeServer2 6/23/2022 22:06:06:66
SomeServer2 6/23/2022 22:08:06:86
SomeServer2 6/23/2022 22:11:06:116
SomeServer2 6/23/2022 22:15:06:156
SomeServer2 6/23/2022 22:16:06:166
```

Final Result set

```
Servername  Start   End Minutes
SomeServer1 6/23/2022 21:48:02:482  6/23/2022 21:52:03:523  4
SomeServer2 6/23/2022 22:03:05:35   6/23/2022 22:06:06:66   3
SomeServer1 6/23/2022 22:15:06:156  6/23/2022 22:16:06:166  1
```

Comment: Please provide data within the question, without using images or links

Comment: the data is in the link?

Comment:  [why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: That's why I'm requesting you to move it into the question because it needs to be stand alone

Comment: dataset is to big to post here. I needed to be enough data to account for all the examples a smaller dataset would create back and forth

Comment: Just a sample dataset of say 10 rows will do.

Comment: Usually, you can't just do a WHERE <your desired value> to calculate things like consecutive <something>. Instead you build "groups" of values using your desired vs. undesired values, then calculate min / max date for them, and then finally it's easy. There's a bunch of gaps and island-like answers here that can be used as inspiration

Comment: I was following another post and in theory that should work but its not working for me. When I go back to validate the time frame I am finding values over 10 for system_idle_process which should break the sequence of time but it does not happen. I an reposting the revised query

Comment: What version of SQL Server? You definitely shouldn't be using cursors for this

Comment: Martin I had a deadline and no one here was giving me a solution. If you can provide a better solution post it. This cursor took 3 hours to complete. Not using a cursor took 18 hours and didnt not finish plus it brought down SQL.

Comment: You still haven't answered my question about version

Comment: MS SQL server 2019

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything need to answer question was provided. Answer was provided from Expertsxchange site it was totally possible with info provided.

```
SELECT t1.ServerName, t1.rn, t1.Event_time, 
 CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(SECOND, FORMAT(t1.[Event_time], 'yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:00'), FORMAT(t2.[Event_time], 'yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:00')) BETWEEN 59 AND 61 THEN 60 
    ELSE 120 END AS secs, 
 CAST(0 AS INT) grp
INTO #temp
FROM CTE t1
    JOIN CTE t2 
        ON t1.ServerName = t2.ServerName 
            AND t1.rn = t2.rn-1
ORDER BY t1.ServerName, t1.Event_time


CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX [ix_Primary] ON  #temp
(
    [ServerName] ASC,
    [Event_Time] ASC
)WITH 
(PAD_INDEX = OFF, 
STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, 
DROP_EXISTING = OFF, 
ONLINE = OFF, 
ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, 
OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) 


DECLARE @srv VARCHAR(50), @rn INT, @secs INT, @lastSecs INT = 0, @grp INT = 0, @lastSrv VARCHAR(50) = '%_'

DECLARE cTemp 
CURSOR FOR 
SELECT ServerName, rn, secs 
FROM #temp
ORDER BY rn

OPEN cTemp
FETCH NEXT FROM cTemp INTO @srv, @rn, @secs
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
  IF @secs <> @lastSecs OR @srv <> @lastSrv
  BEGIN
    SET @grp = @grp + 1
    SET @lastSecs = @secs
    SET @lastSrv = @srv
  END
  UPDATE #temp
  SET grp = @grp 
  WHERE rn = @rn
  FETCH NEXT FROM cTemp INTO @srv, @rn, @secs
END

CLOSE cTemp
DEALLOCATE cTemp

Drop table if exists #temp3
SELECT ServerName, COUNT(*) Minutes_streak, MIN(Event_time) date_group, DATEADD(SECOND, 60, MAX(Event_time)) event_time 
into #temp3
FROM #temp
WHERE secs = 60
GROUP BY ServerName, grp
ORDER BY 3-- ServerName, grp
```

Answer (score 1):

> this logic does not seem to reset time back to 0 when the
> System_Idle_Process goes above the 10 percent threshold

You have a `WHERE System_Idle_Process <=10` so this eliminates all rows with the "above" value.

You can leave those in and use the below logic.

```
DECLARE @System_Idle_Target INT = 10;

WITH T1 AS
(
SELECT *, 
       IsBelowTgt = CASE WHEN System_Idle_Process <= @System_Idle_Target THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
       Prev_System_Idle_Process = LAG(System_Idle_Process) OVER (PARTITION BY ServerName ORDER BY Event_Time),
       IsPrevBelowTgt = CASE WHEN LAG(System_Idle_Process) OVER (PARTITION BY ServerName ORDER BY Event_Time) <= @System_Idle_Target THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
       Prev_Event_Time = LAG(Event_Time) OVER (PARTITION BY ServerName ORDER BY Event_Time)
FROM  dbo.ServerCpuUtilization
), T2 AS
(
SELECT *,
       Grp = SUM(CASE WHEN IsBelowTgt = IsPrevBelowTgt THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY ServerName ORDER BY Event_Time ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
FROM T1
)
SELECT ServerName, 
       COUNT(*) AS RowsInGroup, 
       MIN(Event_Time) AS [Start], 
       MAX(Event_Time) AS [End], 
       DATEDIFF(MINUTE, MIN(Event_Time), MAX(Event_Time)) AS Diff
FROM T2 
WHERE IsBelowTgt = 0
GROUP BY ServerName, Grp
ORDER BY ServerName, Grp
```

Or if you want to stick with the current logic of just excluding them all up front and assuming a gap in the minutes indicates the level must have been breached you can use

```
WITH T1 AS
(
SELECT *, 
       Prev_Event_Time = LAG(Event_Time) OVER (PARTITION BY ServerName ORDER BY Event_Time)
FROM  dbo.ServerCpuUtilization
WHERE System_Idle_Process <=10 
), T2 AS
(
SELECT *,
       Grp = SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(MINUTE, Prev_Event_Time, Event_Time) = 1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY ServerName ORDER BY Event_Time ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
FROM T1
)
SELECT ServerName, 
       COUNT(*) AS RowsInGroup, 
       MIN(Event_Time) AS [Start], 
       MAX(Event_Time) AS [End], 
       DATEDIFF(MINUTE, MIN(Event_Time), MAX(Event_Time)) AS Diff
FROM T2 
GROUP BY ServerName, Grp
ORDER BY ServerName, Grp
```

Depending on how you want minutes with no data at all to be treated you may prefer a combination approach and use

```
SUM(CASE WHEN IsBelowTgt = IsPrevBelowTgt AND DATEDIFF(MINUTE, Prev_Event_Time, Event_Time) = 1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)
```